# Changing the values of a dataframe row by row with a new value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm new to Python so excuse me for any obvious errors made by me.

For this script, I am trying to change the new dates I've inputted based on the day of the week of the original day.

For instance, if 1/1/2022 was a Monday and the date I input was 01/01/2023 a Tuesday, the date I input would automatically change to 31/12/2022 along with the rest of the days in the column.

So far, I've programmed how to find the day of the week based on the date and turn it into a numerical value. Next, I am trying to test out a for loop but keep running into errors. Would love for someone to explain how I can overcome this barrier before I move onto the step.

Thanks!

Example of the CSV file:

```
|     A     | 
| --------- | 
| 01/04/2022|
| 02/04/2022|
| 03/04/2022|
| 04/04/2022|
| --------- |
| 31/12/2022|
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from datetime import datetime

#dataframe
df = pd.read_excel("Test.xlsx", usecols = [0], header=None, names=['colA'])

#types
df.dtypes

#convert date to day
df = \
pd.to_datetime(df['colA']).dt.weekday

#print
print(df)

#iloc over a dataframe

def new_Date(df, col):
    for i in df.index:
        A_val = df[col].iloc[0]
        if A_val == 0:
            df.at[i,col] + 1

new_Date(df, 'colA')
```

Output

```
0       0
1       1
2       2
3       3
4       4
       ..
1091    6
1092    0
1093    1
1094    2
1095    3
Name: colA, Length: 1096, dtype: int64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel.py in <module>
         27             df.at[i,col] + 1
         28 
    ---> 29 new_Date(df, 'colA')
         30 
         31 
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel.py in new_Date(df, col)
         23 def new_Date(df, col):
         24     for i in df.index:
    ---> 25         A_val = df['colA'].iloc[0]
         26         if A_val == 0:
         27             df.at[i,col] + 1
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        940 
        941         elif key_is_scalar:
    --> 942             return self._get_value(key)
        943 
        944         if is_hashable(key):
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
       1049 
       1050         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
    -> 1051         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
       1052         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
       1053 
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
        386                 except ValueError as err:
        387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
    --> 388             raise KeyError(key)
        389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
        390 
    KeyError: 'colA'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have a stack dump to go with the error message you show?  If so, you should include that as part of the error in your question.  The stack dump is often more valuable than the text of the error message.  Another really helpful thing would be to show a few lines if your input spreadsheet, or better still, replace the reading of an Excel spreadsheet with inline data, maybe as JSON or CSV.  You should strive to add enough info to your question that someone can reproduce your problem easily.  Obviously, without your spreadsheet, one can't do that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and your suggestions. I've included an example of what the CSV file would look like and the output/stack dump below.

Comment: just a quick note:  use `pd.read_csv()` for a csv file...  its a bit easier and designed for purpose.

Comment: There are a number of typo, syntax and coding errors in your script. #1 you must have used `colA` somewhere which is not shown in the code you provide. #2 `df[col].iloc[0]` will be rejected as df.iloc[0] would identify the (first row); but why is it in a loop when it is always the first row #3 `df.at[i,col] + 1` has no meaning in Python/Pandas and anyway you do not do anything with expression. You need to re-think the code.

Comment: @user19077881 thanks for the suggestion. I've amended #1, I changed colA to column A to make it easier for people to understand. #2 the loops is meant to start at the first row so I thought to include .iloc[0]. #3 ah okay, I will try another function - do you have any in mind?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly.  The example you give makes no sense.  The days of the week don't match what you say and I don't get why the weekday that a particular day of the month (1/1/2023) fell on in the prior year (1/1/2022) would be significant.  I'm guessing that what you want to do is change all dates to be the prior Monday of the same week if the date is not already a Monday.

If you have a dataframe with a column named 'column_A' containing strings that are dates, and you want to change that column to contain date values that represent the Monday prior to each current value, you can do this:

```
df["column_A"] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_A']).dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time
```

If you wanted to instead use Thursday of that same week, you could do:

```
df["column_A"] = pd.to_datetime(df['column_A']).dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time + pd.Timedelta(3, unit='d')
```